# How to use a list inside values_list() in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am new to python and django.I am having a list obtained dynamically containing database table fieldnames. How do I use this list within values_list() in django queryset while fetching results from database?

```
fieldList=['field1','field2'] #list containing table fields
obj=sampletable.objects.filter(somecondition).values_list(fieldlist) #--->want like this
```

I came to know that we can't use lists simply as it is inside values_list().So I converted it into a string like this and then tried it but in vain.

```
fieldListstr=','.join(repr(e) for e in fieldList)
```

This is the error which I got

```
Cannot resolve keyword "'field1','field2'" into field. Choices are: field1, field2
```

Please help me with your solutions. And thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [argument list unpacking](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) to pass the values of a list as arguments to a function like so:

```
values_list(*fieldlist)
```

Comment: Do you feel any difference between your answer the other one ?

Comment: I added a short description of what is happening and a link to the documentation for better understanding.

Comment: The link does make this the better answer

Answer (score 9):

Simply unpack them,

```
.values_list(*fieldlist)
```